# Is the SILC protocol still used?

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis

I'm looking into implementing a private SILC server for friends (and possibly their friends).

And after visiting the Wikipedia entry for [SILC protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILC_%28protocol%29), it seems all the official pages linked at the bottom are dead with only a few anon servers here and there.

Is it still being used nowadays?
And if it is ... where(online) are more resources (howto's and/or daemon software)?

And if it isn't used anymore... are there any security reasons involved?

Is the security model or the used cryptographic protocols and algorithms flawed thanks to exploit XYZ?

A complementary question would be: are there any more current alternatives available now?

another complimentary question would be:are there any public and/or anon servers still online ?

and ..does it use much system ressources on a server let's say for 50 concurrent users ?
(this is just a complimentary question if you feel you can answer :)

Comment: incidently.. since it is my first question here..
is it a question i should be asking here ? :)

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. I edited your question to look a bit better. I think it is a bit near the borderline of on-topicness, but still on our side.

Comment: nice to hear that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SILC is still used daily by a few of us die hards. :-)

I, too, noticed the other day that the official source repos are dead. Perhaps we can get them up on Github or other hosting site.

I haven't heard of any flaws discovered in the protocol itself, but I haven't heard of anyone reviewing it lately either.

Comment: but i remember reading a while ago.. that the current version wasn't implementing opengpg (among others) in its current implementation.. although the protocol design permits it..

Comment: in the current context (i'm in canada) of new internet legislation
..which (might)remove some amount of privacy.. i have a feeling that more and more people will be interested by one such protocol in the near future :)
so.. a github would be a welcome addition..

Comment: Probably mpOTR would be a better choice for new usage.